# many-to-many relationship in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, relational-database, flask-sqlalchemy

I just switched from MySQL to SQLalchemy and I have to say that it is more difficult to get my head around sqlalchemy than I thought. Currently I have some trouble with a many-to-many relationship. I have users and queries in my model. A user can have many queries and a query offers a new article to read every day. I want to store which user read which query on what date. My models.py looks like this

```
class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    read_dates = db.relationship("ReadIndex", backref="user")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.id)

class Queries(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Queries %r>' % (self.id)


class ReadIndex(db.Model):

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    query_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('queries.id'), primary_key=True)
    read_datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    read_query = db.relationship("Queries", backref="user_assocs")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ReadIndex>'
```

so I have users and queries. To store which user read which query on what date I have the class ReadIndex, which has an extra field called read_datetime, where I store the date of a user-query association. I than want to add such an association like

```
user = models.User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
query = models.Queries.query.filter_by(id=query_id).first()
a = models.ReadIndex(read_datetime=dt.utcnow())
a.read_query = query
user.read_dates.append(a)
db.session.commit()
```

where query_id and user_id are the corresponding ids to select my objects. If I run this I get an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError
IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed:
read_index.query_id [SQL: u'INSERT INTO read_index (user_id, read_datetime) 
VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (1, '2015-07-29 20:55:50.898366')]
```

I am not sure what the problem is? I don't seem to violate any NOT NULL

edit: I noticed that I assigned query=None to a.read_query. Correcting this slightly changed the error

```
IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush;  
consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) 
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: read_index.user_id 
[SQL: u'INSERT INTO read_index (query_id, read_datetime) VALUES (?, ?)'] 
[parameters: (1, '2015-07-29 23:11:11.934038')]
```

here is exactly what happens:

```
>>> from app import app, db, models
>>> user = models.User.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
>>> user
<User u'Florian Beutler'>
>>> query = models.Queries.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
>>> query
<Queries 1>
>>> import datetime
>>> a = models.ReadIndex(read_datetime=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
>>> a.read_query = query
>>> user.read_dates.append(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 237, in __get__
    return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 578, in get
    value = self.callable_(state, passive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 529, in _load_for_state
    return self._emit_lazyload(session, state, ident_key, passive)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 599, in _emit_lazyload
    result = q.all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2399, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2515, in __iter__
    self.session._autoflush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1292, in _autoflush
    util.raise_from_cause(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1282, in _autoflush
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2004, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2122, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2086, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 373, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 532, in execute
    uow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 174, in save_obj
mapper, table, insert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 781, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: read_index.user_id [SQL: u'INSERT INTO read_index (query_id, read_datetime) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (1, '2015-07-29 23:17:06.013485')]
```

constraint?
thanks
carl

Answer (score 0):

The `.first()` method either returns the first result or `None` if there isn't one, are you sure you're not assigning `a.read_query` to `None`?

Comment: Hi fish, thanks for your reply. Indeed I originally assigned None, but correcting this did not solve the issue. I updated the post above to show what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the user_id and query_id fields of the ReadIndex table are None. So, when you commit, ReadIndex object is trying to get created without having values in its primary key fields. So, do this,

```
user = models.User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
query = models.Queries.query.filter_by(id=query_id).first()
a=models.ReadIndex(user_id=user.id,query_id=query.id,read_datetime=dt.utcnow())
db.session.add(a)
db.session.commit()
```

You dont need to manually append anything to the relationship. SQLAlchemy does that for you automatically. You can crosscheck if you want,

```
for ud in user.read_dates:
    print(ud)
```

Hope this helps!